# Compute hatching rate by extracting value from month before

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, time

I need to compute hatching rates in R.
Every month I get number of eggs for incubation and number of hatchlings.
But often they do not hatch within the same month.

So I need to get
hatch[current month]/egg[previous month]

```
 structure(list(company = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "Farm1", class = "factor"), 
    Monate = structure(1:12, levels = c("Dezember", "Jänner", 
    "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", 
    "September", "Oktober", "November"), class = "factor"), egg = c(56851L, 
    85781L, 4540L, 32368L, 65205L, 92985L, 44083L, 18689L, 30720L, 
    88884L, 78506L, 86771L), hatch = c(14746L, 69977L, 58173L, 
    92517L, 63289L, 83197L, 99357L, 46222L, 57884L, 73390L, 93159L, 
    63855L)), out.attrs = list(dim = c(company = 2L, Monate = 12L, 
egg = 1L, hatch = 1L), dimnames = list(company = c("company=Farm1", 
"company=Farm2"), Monate = c("Monate=Dezember", "Monate=Jänner", 
"Monate=Februar", "Monate=März", "Monate=April", "Monate=Mai", 
"Monate=Juni", "Monate=Juli", "Monate=August", "Monate=September", 
"Monate=Oktober", "Monate=November"), egg = "egg=53553", hatch = "hatch=69057")), row.names = c(1L, 
3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L), class = "data.frame") 

Month names in my data set are in German:
monats_name_de <- c("Dezember","Jänner","Februar","März","April",
                    "Mai","Juni","Juli","August","September",
                    "Oktober","November","Dezember")
Starting with Dezember - I thought that is better
```

The best would be that simple the rate gets attached to the original data frame.

```
 get_earlier <- function(x){
farm$hatch[farm$Monate==farm$Monate[x]]/
    farm$egg[farm$Monate[x] == monats_name_de[((farm$Monate[x] == monats_name_de) %>% which)-1]] %>% unique
}

sapply(seq_along(farm$Monate), get_earlier)
```

But it does not calculate any numbers.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this in R is to use the `lag()` function from the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

farm |> mutate(rate = hatch/lag(egg), .by = company)
```

Output:

```
   company    Monate   egg hatch       rate
1    Farm1  Dezember 56851 14746         NA
3    Farm1    Jänner 85781 69977  1.2308842
5    Farm1   Februar  4540 58173  0.6781572
7    Farm1      März 32368 92517 20.3781938
9    Farm1     April 65205 63289  1.9552954
11   Farm1       Mai 92985 83197  1.2759298
13   Farm1      Juni 44083 99357  1.0685272
15   Farm1      Juli 18689 46222  1.0485221
17   Farm1    August 30720 57884  3.0972230
19   Farm1 September 88884 73390  2.3889974
21   Farm1   Oktober 78506 93159  1.0480964
23   Farm1  November 86771 63855  0.8133773
```

This assumes that your data is in order, and you're not missing any months. It's quite straightforward to create a date column.

One issue with the approach you are using is it can only handle one year's worth of data- if you include more than one year, you'll start to get the wrong month of data.

With that said, the issue with your code is the [x] in 'farm$egg[farm$Monate ***[x]***' etc.. It turns what should be a vector of trues and falses into just one - because you're comparing not against the whole Monate column, but just the one in the column you're already in. The fixed code would be:

```
get_earlier <- function(x){
  farm$hatch[farm$Monate == farm$Monate[x]]/
  farm$egg[farm$Monate == monats_name_de[(farm$Monate[x] == monats_name_de) |> which() - 1]]
}
```

This still breaks on the data (get_earlier(1) gets the number of eggs for the November in the future!), so I'd recommend creating a date column, or using lag() instead!

Comment: I followed your instructions and it worked. But I would like to have more "stable" way to compute it (because I bit mistrust the beforehand sorting). But with my later function, I would overcome that.. Ineed to retry it. But I will need to split my dataset beforehand..

Comment: when you say "stable", what precisely do you mean? Tolerant to the rows not being in the correct order?

Comment: It would be perhaps easier for me to have it ready as a data frame. I plan to plot the number of eggs and hatches, I would like to export it for a report. So I would need to re-arrange my original data frame

Comment: I don't know if I follow, but if you need help, feel free to ask another question here, or as a separate thing 

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my way. Not sure if there is a more efficient way:

```
get_earlier_numbers <- function(df){
    lapply(1:nrow(df),function(x){
    new_arraged_df <- data.frame(
      # company = df$company[x],
      Schlupf_Monat = df$Monate[x],
      Einlage_Monat = monats_name_de[((df$Monate[x] == monats_name_de) %>% which)-1] %>% unique,
      Schlupf = df$hatch[df$Monate == df$Monate[x]],
      Einlage = df$egg[df$Monate == (monats_name_de[((df$Monate[x] == monats_name_de) %>% which)-1] %>% unique)])
      })
    rearranged_dfs <- do.call(rbind,by_company) %>% as.data.frame
    return(rearranged_dfs)}
    
    new_farm_list <- lapply(list_farm,get_earlier_numbers)
    farm <- do.call(rbind,new_farm_list)
    
    farm$schlupfrate <- farm$Schlupf/farm$Einlage
```